# Apache spark dataset save new updated value in DB by adding old value with new value

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-dataset

My stack is Apache Spark 2.0, Spark Cassandra Java Connector, Cassandra 3.7

Here is my requirement.

I have created a dataset (ds1) by fetching a column family data into my Java program. The next step is getting new data from the external source into new dataset (ds2). The schema of both datasets is exactly same. But now the problem is while saving the new values from ds2 into the database, I want to update a column in such a way that its previous value (ds1.col1) will be added with new value (ds2.col1) and then save the new updated value to database i.e. (ds2.col1 + ds1.col1).

At present I am getting the value of ds1.col1 by following way

```
Dataset<SomeClass> existingData = ds1.filter((ds1.primarykey == ds2.primaryKey)? true : false);

myList = existingData.takeAsList(1);

Dataset<SomeClass>  dataFromDB = myList.get(0);


ds2.setCol1(newVal + dataFromDB.getCol1()); //This is how I save the new value in databse. (previous value + new value)
```

As far as I read about  takeAsList() it has impact on performance. What could be another efficient way to do this? Please let me know your inputs.
If you need more information, then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it that `ds1` and `ds1` are of type `DataSet`? In that case you cannot do `ds1.filter((ds1.primarykey == ds2.primaryKey)...`. In stead you need to join you datasets and then use `map` to generate the new result set.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt yes they are 2 datasets. but I just used it to explain my requirement. Actually it is ds1.filter((ds1.primarykey == NewPrimaryKey)...